# Text doesn't show upon background in html

Tags: html, css, web

I have an idiot question if you may, I can't find an answer for this thing;

I'm trying to code a new website at the moment, I've done the background and nothing to fear of!

Now, the text is moving the background aside! Let me show you[image: problem]

and what it should be , is upon the background without moving it!

The code:

*HTML*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Evasion Online</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
         <div id="header">
         </div>
         <div id="navigator"><!--START NAV-->
            <div class="nav"><!--START NAV CLASS-->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#">Download</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li><br>
                    <li><a href="#">Shit</a></li><br>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            </div><!--END NAV CLASS-->
         </div><!--END NAV-->
            <div id="nav">

           </div>
           <div id="leftside"><!--START LEFTSIDE-->
                <div class="statistics">

                </div>
                <div class="rank">

                </div>
            </div><!--END LEFTSIDE-->
            <div id="main"><!--START MAIN-->
                <div class="news">

                </div>
            </div><!--END MAIN-->
            <div id="rightside"><!--START RIGHTSIDE-->
                <div class="login">

                </div>
                <div class="exclusive">

                </div>
            </div><!--END RIGHTSIDE-->

            <div id="block_content">

            </div>

            <div id="footer">

            </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*CSS*:

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {   margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}
table{
margin: 0;  padding: 0;     font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/*#############*/
/*STARTING CSS*/

body{
    background:url('imgs/bg.png') top center no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    font-size:12px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#wrapper {
    width:1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    float: left;
    background:url('imgs/header.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:1280px; height:837px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
a {
    display: block;
}
.nav{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.nav ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.nav li{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.15em;
}

#leftside{
    float:left;
    background:url('imgs/leftside.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:346px; height:788px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#main{
    float:left;
    background:url('imgs/main.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:585px; height:788px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#rightside{
    float:left;
    background:url('imgs/rightside.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:349px; height:788px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
#footer {
    float:left;
    background:url('imgs/footer.jpg') no-repeat;
    width:1280px; height:333px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.container {
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? or add another image with the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from your picture and code how you want the background to appear. However, if you just want a fixed background to cover the whole page whatever's on it, just define the background image for the body.

If the divs like main have their own backgrounds, then these will move around with the divs, depending on what's in them, and resizing the browser will make them wriggle all over the place.

You might want to set the background style for your nav element too, to get rid of the white background. Try

```
nav { background-color:transparent; }
```

Comment: Nope, resizing the browser did not change anything and they're fixed and perfect..
and what I want to do is the following:
You see home regsiter and so on?
they're white backgrounded,
I want to remove that white background and instead of making the code push the background image like the preview, no, I want the background image to stay where it was and the home, register and so on become UPON the background. sorry if I'm not able to explain what I want exactly

Comment: By the way, background-color:transparent; did not work.

Comment: see edit - I'd guess the white bg is coming from the nav - try that and then maybe the class nav and its children if you need to

Comment: and make sure you do a hard refresh ctrl +F5 to pull in the new stylesheet

Comment: and beware, you have both the element nav and the class nav in your html

Comment: I just copied your code and pasted it into two files. Then edited one line so I didn't have to worry about the background images, I set the background of body to grey. Your text appeared over a grey background like the rest of the page. I don't think you're looking at the latest version of your stylesheet - try the hard refresh.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!

I had just to put it inside the header tag.. Sorry for wasting your time guys!

Thanks for the helping outhere.